# it should terminate when user enters -1

Tags: c++, arrays

In this array every integer except the last one is positive. The last integer is (-1).Find the length (size) of the array.

```
int number;
int i=0;
cout << "Enter a number ";
cin >> number;
array[0] == number;
for (int i = 1; i<array[i]; i++){
    cout << "Enter a number for your array: ";
    cin >> array[i];
    }

    if (array[i] == -1){
        cout << i;
}
return 0;
```

Why it isn`t terminating on -1. It's keep on iterating

Comment: `i<array[i];` Sure?? Not rather `i<number;` or something alike?

Comment: 1) What is `array`? 2) Why should it terminate once you enter `-1`? There's no check for it, in the loop.

Comment: In this code, do you want to keep asking new numbers until a negative number? Or until a number lower than the array?

Comment: @DavidAlves it should keep inputting numbers from user until user enters "-1" like a terminating point. So as the user enters (-1) the program should terminate and print the size of array

Comment: @AbdullahMujahid Use something like `std::vector<int> array;` and `array.push_back(number);` until `-1` was entered for `number`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
int number;
int i=0;
cout << "Enter a number ";
cin >> number;
array[0] == number;

while (number != -1){
    cout << "Enter a number for your array: ";
    cin >> number;
    i++;
    array[i] = number;
}

cout << i;

return 0;
```

Comment: it was perfectly executed.